# the hive can't create map/reduce job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, diagnostics

i have used hive-0.11.0, hadoop 2.0.3, and mysql 5.6 for metadata

i can successful run the statement like SELECT * FROM records,which not create a map/reduce task.

But when i try run SELECT * FROM records where year='1949' the map/reduce task always get some error

the hadoop give me Diagnostics:
Application application_1382680612829_0136 failed 1 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1382680612829_0136_000001 exited with exitCode: -1000 due to: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/nm-local-dir/filecache does not exist at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:492) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.primitiveMkdir(FileSystem.java:996) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DelegateToFileSystem.mkdir(DelegateToFileSystem.java:150) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFs.mkdir(FilterFs.java:187) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$4.next(FileContext.java:730) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$4.next(FileContext.java:726) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$FSLinkResolver.resolve(FileContext.java:2379) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.mkdir(FileContext.java:726) at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.createDir(FSDownload.java:88) at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:274) at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:51) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) .Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.

what i should do? thanks

Comment: It is indicating you a java.io.FileNotFoundExceptiona bout File /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/nm-local-dir/filecache, is it an element into your environment configuration?

Comment: i'm not sure about it. i run set -v in hive shell. and get a line likehadoop.tmp.dir=/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}. is it? @emecas

Comment: I'm not sure. I have posted as a answer the summary of the best reference I've found about that Exception you are getting. is your hadoop 2.0.3 instalation the last release? Be sure it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, as solution they recommend to create the  parent folders, there is also a patch that is supposed to be fixed at 2.0.3 [[1]](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-253)

> Tom White added a comment - 30/Nov/12 21:36 This fixes the problem by
>   creating parent directories if they don't already exist. Without the
>   fix the test would fail about 4 times in 10; with the fix I didn't see
>   a failure.

It looks like the most similar issue that I could find in the hadoop bugs database

It's also related to [[2]](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-152) and [[3]](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-420) if you want to take a look

Comment: thanks a lot, i find it is because i didn't set hadoop tmp director, so it has been created in the /tmp, and be deleted by the system. so i try to re-format the hadoop and it be fixed